# Erro ao fazer o cast EditText

Tags: android

Estou com um problema no meu projeto de salvar os campos após as alterações. Na tela de detalhes eu tenho um botão de alterar que quando clico ele joga para esta tela que está abaixo: Eu acredito que o erro deva estar no XML, pois se eu apenas jogar um EditText na tela eu funciona. Alguém sabe o porque disso ?
O erro que dá é que ele não consegue fazer o cast no Edit Text.

```
start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.aula.primeirobanco/br.com.aula.primeirobanco.Editar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

Meu xml está assim:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconeFilme"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_people_icon"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alteracaoNome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconeFilme"
            android:text="@string/detalhesNome"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Mas no meu código JAVA ele dá erro:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);

    id = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("id");
    nome = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("nome");
    sinopse = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("sinopse");
    duracao = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("duracao");

    gravarAlteracao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoGravarAlteracao);
    nomeAlterado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoNome);
    sinopseAlterada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoSinopse);
    duracaoAlterada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoDuracao);
```

Vou anexar as imagens para melhor entendimento:

XML: [image: XML da alteração]

JAVA: [image: Java da alteração]

Comment: `alteraçãoNome` está declarado no *xml* como um *TextView* e não como um *EditText*

Comment: @ramaral Mesmo se eu colocar o nomeAlterado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoNome); ele dá erro e solicita para fazer o cast e mudar para EditText.

Comment: Isso porque ele está(suponho, não consigo ver) declarado no java como *EditText*.

Comment: @ramaral Isto mesmo. Muito obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alteracaoNome".....
```

No java:

```
 nomeAlterado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoNome);
```

Como dito no erro, não é possível realizar o `cast` entre objetos diferentes!

Se o usuário irá editar o campo, este deve ser um `EditText`, então será necessário alterar o **xml** .

Caso os dados serão apenas para visualização, então será necessário alterar o seu **Java**.

Exemplo:

```
TextView nomeAlterado;

 nomeAlterado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alteracaoNome);
```